# How to know if imgur link is album, image or gallery?

Tags: python, python-requests, imgur

If have an imgur link, how do I know if it's a single image, an album or a gallery, the API has a lot of methods of what to do with images, albums and galleries but it's not very clear how I can get this information from the link.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to get imgur content type from imgur API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35210559/easiest-way-to-get-imgur-content-type-from-imgur-api)